# ¿Como instalo angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular5

Necesito crear un proyecto en angular 4 pero cuando lo creo lo hace con angular 5. Como puedo crear el proyecto en angular 4 ?

Comment: Hola jesus jose, falta algo de información en la pregunta:¿cómo estás creando el proyecto? ¿Es a través de un programa o con algún comando desde la línea de comandos? Lee [ask] y dale a [edit] la pregunta para añadir más información.

Comment: En qué sistema operativo??

Comment: la manera no muy elegante es crearlo con cli y cambiarle la version en el package.json

Comment: Si vas a crear el proyecto desde cero, por qué no ir a la versión más moderna? la versión 5 tiene novedades interesantes, sobre todo en temas de AJAX (HttpClient en lugar de Http, por ejemplo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la instalación es a través de `npm`, puedes especificar la versión utilizando:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.9
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Si lo haces por consola con angular-cli, puedes crearlo sin generar el node_modules ng new myProject --skip-install

Despues bajas la versión de tu package.json y haces el npm install